# How to find city temperature by longitude and latitude in android?

Tags: android

how to find city temperature by longitude and latitude....
Does anyone know of a service with an API or a widget that I could use to display weather based on geographical coordinates?

Comment: Check this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951839/api-to-get-weather-based-on-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates

Answer (score 26, accepted):

we can find city temp by using this find_Location Class. in which firstly find the city location by use by longitude and latitude in android? And after that use the method  SendToUrl to find the temperature by use GoogleXML "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query="

```
public void find_Location(Context con)
    {
        Log.d("Find Location", "in find_location");
        this.con=con;
        String location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)con.getSystemService(location_context);

        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
       for (String provider : providers) 
       {
           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,new LocationListener()
           {
               public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
               public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
               public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
               public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle  extras){}
           });
           Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
           if (location != null)
           {
               latitude = location.getLatitude();
               longitude = location.getLongitude();
               addr=ConvertPointToLocation(latitude,longitude);
                       String temp_c=SendToUrl(addr);

           } 
       }
    }

    public String ConvertPointToLocation(double pointlat,double pointlog) {

        String address = "";
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(con,
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(pointlat,pointlog, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0)
                        .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                    address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return address;
    }  

    private String  SendToUrl(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          try{
              string=string.replace(" ","%20");

        String queryString="http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query="+string;
        url= new URL(queryString);

        conec= url.openConnection();
        stream = conec.getInputStream();
        xpp = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(stream, null);
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
              if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {String elementName = xpp.getName();
                  if("temp_c".equals(elementName))
                    {
                               int acount=xpp.getAttributeCount();
                   for(int x=0;x<acount;x++) 
            {
            xpp.getAttributeValue(x);          
                        String str=xpp.getAttributeValue(x);
                     return str;
         }  

          }
      }
      eventType = xpp.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your data types for xpp, conec and stream?

Answer (score 4):

Google Weather API is not supported now. So the above code will not work now.
You can use the following url , pass your current location latitude , longitude and you will get resultant xml from which you can extract the desired info.

http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.78158&lon=-73.96648&FcstType=dwml

Answer (score 3):

My answer is not totally perfect but [Yahoo Weather API](http://code.google.com/p/yahooweatherandroid/) may help you. This worked perfectly for me.

In this api you have to select one of the City and then you will get weather updates. However you have to go through the source for extracting your portion.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a full code example on [anddev.org google weather api description](http://www.anddev.org/android_weather_forecast_-_google_weather_api_-_description-t337.html) which should include everything you require.

Comment: anddev.org was taken over, and appears to be selling medicines in Japanese

Comment: Can be accessed via [wayback machine - google weather api description](https://web.archive.org/web/20111002154030/http://www.anddev.org/android_weather_forecast_-_google_weather_api_-_description-t337.html)
... but yes, this answer is probably not my best work.  I am providing this update for those it may help.