# How to get current Temperature in android app?

Tags: android, widget

I am developing an android application. i want to show current temperature in it . how can i achieve this? I am Using AVD for testing.

Comment: I'm not aware of any devices that contain a thermometer. Or do you mean you want to pull it from the internet for your local zip code?

Comment: You want to know the temperature of Device or Particular city. If City means, [Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7077112/940096)

Comment: @SpK Google shut down their weather api.

Comment: Then, just try [Yahoo Weather API](http://code.google.com/p/yahooweatherandroid/)

Comment: i want to pull it from the internet for my Zip code.

Comment: Thanks to all. your great response is precious for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to show the ambient temperature, I'm afraid that's not possible without a built-in thermometer. And I've never heard of a device with that feature. But even if there were one, you surely cannot do it with an AVD.

On the other hand you could use location-based weather APIs to get an approximate temperature of your town/city.

[Wunderground Weather API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/)
Free 500 calls/day - 10 calls/min (Or pay for more)

[Yahoo Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)

[World Weather Online Free API](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather.aspx)

[World Weather Online Paid API](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/premium-weather.aspx)